# New project file organization

Tags: file-browser

Is there a shortcut to set up project file folders so that you end up with a folder of folders that are pre-named? Like for Maya, you would choose File-New-New Project. You would then name the project folder, but the folders inside it would be pre-named "scene" and "textures" and "renders" etc.

Comment: As far as I know it is all embedded within the the .blend file. You can access it from the outliner by changing the view layer to -> .blend file.